# Tkinter grid fill empty space

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I did search for a lot of examples before posting but still can't properly use the tkinter grid.

***What I want:***

[image]

my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text='b1')
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

e1 = ttk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

t = ttk.Treeview(root)
t.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.NS)

scroll.configure(command=t.yview)
t.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `t.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)` to `t.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the treeview and the scrollbar but the entry still have the empty space when the window is resized.

Comment: You want the entry field to expand with the window?

Comment: It already does expand to the right side with the window but it gets to far from the button.

Comment: That is because of the weight you set on row 0. You can fix that by deleting `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`. See my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The quick and simple solution is to define the `columnspan` of the `treeview`. This will tell the treeview to spread across 2 columns and allow the entry field to sit next to your button.

On an unrelated note you can use strings for your `sticky` so you do not have to do things like `tk.E+tk.NS`. Instead simply use `"nse"` or whatever directions you need. Make sure thought you are doing them in order of `"nsew"`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text='b1')
b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

e1 = ttk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")

t = ttk.Treeview(root)
t.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew") # columnspan=2 goes here.

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nse") # set this to column=2 so it sits in the correct spot.

scroll.configure(command=t.yview)
t.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) Removing this line fixes the sizing issue with the entry field.
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

To fix your issue you mention in the comments you can delete `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to get the entry to expand properly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, i would never done it myself :)

Comment: @VítorNunes sure thing. If my answer solved your problem please make sure to indicate your issue has been resoled by selecting the check mark next to my answer.